# Appending point (".") in JTextArea with rigth to left orientation

Tags: java, jtextarea, right-to-left

I've come across unusual problem in Java (1.7 JRE), and I can't find a solution.

I am using JTextArea to write text in it, in form of decimal number, for example 123.4 with right to left orientation. Every time I enter "." in turns up at the beginning of the text, like this .123 and when I enter next number it shows up like it should 123.4

It happens both when I try entering numbers with keyboard and via JButtons using method I wrote. Here's the part of the code:

```
        String number;
        JTextArea textAreaUnos;
        .
        .
        .
        number=number+".";
        textAreaUnos.setText(number);
```

I've also tried writing it like this:

```
textAreaUnos.append(".");
```

but the result is the same when I type, for example

```
123
.123
123.4
```

In left to right orientation, this is not happening.

Has anyone had problem like this before, and have you managed to solve it?

Comment: Text orientation is different than localization. You may want to set your localization settings also appropriately.

Comment: Did you set the orientation using `textAreaUnos.applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT)` ? or something similar?

Comment: Yes, that's what I used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One work around is using `JTextPane` or `JEditorPane`. Below is an example of `JTextPane`.

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;

class Demo{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->{
            JFrame frame=new JFrame("Right-Left");
            JTextPane box=new JTextPane();
            frame.getContentPane().add(box);
            SimpleAttributeSet attr = new SimpleAttributeSet();
            StyleConstants.setAlignment(attr, StyleConstants.ALIGN_RIGHT);
            box.setParagraphAttributes(attr, true);
            frame.setSize(300,200);
            frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        });
    }
}
```

[image: This is what you get]

Answer (score 0):

Indeed when you append with `RIGHT_TO_LEFT` a string which start o ends with a non digit nor letter the output is wrong (i.e 123. gets converted to .123)

I managed to append it right by checking if character is `.isLetterOrDigit` and append to Start or End depending on the check. I know it's tricky but it was the only solution i found.

### Main:

```
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Main extends JFrame {
  /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private JTextArea t1 = new JTextArea("", 10, 15), t2;

  public Main() {
    Box b = Box.createHorizontalBox();    
    b.add(new JScrollPane(t1));    
    t2 = new JTextArea(10, 15);
    t2.setEditable(false);
    b.add(new JScrollPane(t2));
    add(b); 
    setSize(425, 200);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    t2.setComponentOrientation ( ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT); 

    t1.addKeyListener ( new KeyListener( )
    {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped ( KeyEvent e )
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased ( KeyEvent e )
        {
            char check = (char)e.getKeyCode ( );
            if(Character.isLetterOrDigit ( check ) )
            {
                t2.setText ( t1.getText ( ).substring ( 0 , t1.getText ( ).length ( )-1 ) + check);

            }
            else 
            {
                t2.setText ( check + t2.getText ( ) );
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed ( KeyEvent e )
        {

        }
    });
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Main();
  }
}
```

### Test:

[image: Testing]

Comment: Um, not hard feelings, but that is really bad use of key event handler. I suspect if that serves the purpose of OP